lucia auth get data from from different table
This is my auth.ts file located in utils folder (I use nuxt 3)
auth.ts
import { Lucia } from "lucia"
import { D1Adapter } from "@lucia-auth/adapter-sqlite"

export function initializeLucia(D1: D1Database) {
  const adapter = new D1Adapter(D1, {
    user: "users",
    session: "session",
  })
  return new Lucia(adapter, {
    sessionCookie: {
      attributes: {
        secure: !import.meta.dev,
      },
    },
    getUserAttributes: (attributes) => {
      return {
        firstname: attributes.first_name,
        lastname: attributes.last_name,
        email: attributes.email,
        username: attributes.username,
        country: attributes.country,
        gender: attributes.gender,
        date_of_birth: attributes.date_of_birth,
        selectedPhoneCode: attributes.selectedPhoneCode,
        phone: attributes.phone,
      }
    },
  })
}


declare module "lucia" {
  interface Register {
    Lucia: ReturnType<typeof initializeLucia>
    DatabaseUserAttributes: DatabaseUserAttributes
  }
}

interface DatabaseUserAttributes {
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
  email: string
  username: string
  country: string
  gender: string
  date_of_birth: string
  selectedPhoneCode: string
  phone: string
}

I need to get user attribute called email_verified which stores string data. The problem is that the current attributes are picking data from table called users but I need to pick data as well from table called account_verification which has row called email_verified which I need.

It's not possible using built-in SQLite adapter.
But you can easily build your own custom adapter based on it. See this code fragment from Lucia repo:
public async getUserSessions(userId: UserId): Promise<DatabaseSession[]> {
    const result = await this.controller.getAll<SessionSchema>(
        `SELECT * FROM ${this.escapedSessionTableName} WHERE user_id = ?`,
        [userId]
    );
    return result.map((val) => {
        return transformIntoDatabaseSession(val);
    });
}

Here you can update the query to join a table of your choice:
`SELECT
    s.*,
    av.email_verified
 FROM
     ${this.escapedSessionTableName} s
     JOIN account_verification av
         ON av.user_id = s.user_id
 WHERE s.user_id = ?`

